# Getting unique objects based on nested object property

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have an object array as follows. I need the unique objects based the _id field of the application object inside the group.

```html
const myObjArray:any = [
    {
        "group": {
            "name": "SAM-admin",
            "active": true,
            "application": {
                "_id": "g4fac238hma10kjo3mv473vbs",
                "name": "Prism",
                "owners": "",
                "url": "",
                "description": "",
                "active": "",
                "created_by": "",
                "updated_by": ""
            },
            "created_by": "",
            "updated_by": "",
        },
        "user": "g4fac238hma10kjo3mv473vbs",
        "role": "g4fac238hma10kjo3mv473vbs",
        "isAdmin": true,
        "active": true,
        "created_by": "Abhilash.Shajan1@gmail.com",
        "updated_by": "",
    },
        {
        "group": {
            "name": "SAM-super-admin",
            "active": true,
            "application": {
                "_id": "g4fac238hma10kjo3mv473asc",
                "name": "Utopia",
                "owners": "",
                "url": "",
                "description": "",
                "active": "",
                "created_by": "",
                "updated_by": ""
            },
            "created_by": "",
            "updated_by": "",
        },
        "user": "g4fac238hma10kjo3mv473asc",
        "role": "g4fac238hma10kjo3mv473asc",
        "isAdmin": true,
        "active": true,
        "created_by": "Hima.Thomas@gmail.com",
        "updated_by": "",
    }
    ,
        {
        "group": {
            "name": "SAM-guest",
            "active": true,
            "application": {
                "_id": "g4fac238hma10kjo3mv473asc",
                "name": "Utopia",
                "owners": "",
                "url": "",
                "description": "",
                "active": "",
                "created_by": "",
                "updated_by": ""
            },
            "created_by": "",
            "updated_by": "",
        },
        "user": "g4fac238hma10kjo3mv473asc",
        "role": "g4fac238hma10kjo3mv473asc",
        "isAdmin": true,
        "active": true,
        "created_by": "Hima.Thomas@gmail.com",
        "updated_by": "",
    }
];
```

Here in `myObjArray` the second and third elements are having group object with same application _id

Hence i need to remove the third object.

How to do this at the easiest way in typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, `Array.reduce` is perfect to grouping array of objects by property. Just pass along as the `acc` parameter an object that will collect all the items as you iterate. Finally, getting the `Object.values` of the result since we don't need the grouping keys.

```js
var data = [{ "group": { "name": "SAM-admin", "active": true, "application": { "_id": "g4fac238hma10kjo3mv473vbs", "name": "Prism", "owners": "", "url": "", "description": "", "active": "", "created_by": "", "updated_by": "" }, "created_by": "", "updated_by": "", }, "user": "g4fac238hma10kjo3mv473vbs", "role": "g4fac238hma10kjo3mv473vbs", "isAdmin": true, "active": true, "created_by": "Abhilash.Shajan1@gmail.com", "updated_by": "", }, { "group": { "name": "SAM-super-admin", "active": true, "application": { "_id": "g4fac238hma10kjo3mv473asc", "name": "Utopia", "owners": "", "url": "", "description": "", "active": "", "created_by": "", "updated_by": "" }, "created_by": "", "updated_by": "", }, "user": "g4fac238hma10kjo3mv473asc", "role": "g4fac238hma10kjo3mv473asc", "isAdmin": true, "active": true, "created_by": "Hima.Thomas@gmail.com", "updated_by": "", }, { "group": { "name": "SAM-guest", "active": true, "application": { "_id": "g4fac238hma10kjo3mv473asc", "name": "Utopia", "owners": "", "url": "", "description": "", "active": "", "created_by": "", "updated_by": "" }, "created_by": "", "updated_by": "", }, "user": "g4fac238hma10kjo3mv473asc", "role": "g4fac238hma10kjo3mv473asc", "isAdmin": true, "active": true, "created_by": "Hima.Thomas@gmail.com", "updated_by": "", } ];

var result = (Object.values(data.reduce(function(acc, item) {
  if (!acc[item.group.application._id]) {
    acc[item.group.application._id] = item;
  }
  return acc;
}, {})));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```